# Prolog multiple predicates in findall/setof

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

I'm trying to find ancestors of the Greek mythological Muses using the following facts and rules (simplified):

```
/* parent(A, B) - A is the parent of B */
parent(zeus, calliope).
parent(zeus, clio).
parent(zeus, melpomene).
parent(zeus, euterpe).
parent(zeus, erato).
parent(zeus, terpsichore).
parent(zeus, urania).
parent(zeus, thalia).
parent(zeus, polymnia).
parent(mnemosyne, calliope).
parent(mnemosyne, clio).
parent(mnemosyne, melpomene).
parent(mnemosyne, euterpe).
parent(mnemosyne, erato).
parent(mnemosyne, terpsichore).
parent(mnemosyne, urania).
parent(mnemosyne, thalia).
parent(mnemosyne, polymnia).

parent(kronos, zeus).
parent(rheia, zeus).
parent(oranos, kronos).
parent(gaia, oranos).
```

The `muse` and ancestor rules are defined as:

```
/* A is a Muse if A's parents are Zeus and Mnemosyne */
muse(A):- parent(zeus, A), parent(mnemosyne, A).
/* A is the ancestor of B if A is the parent of B */
ancestor(A, B):- parent(A, B).
/* A is an ancestor of C if A is the parent of B and B is the ancestor of C */
ancestor(A, C):- parent(A, B), ancestor(B, C).
```

I want to essentially do the following:

```
/* Get the set of ancestors A of muses B and store in Z*/
setof(A, ancestor(A, muse(B)), Z).
```

This doesn't work, and returns `false`. Another variant I tried:

```
findall(B, muse(B), Muses),
setof(A, ancestor(A, Muses), Z).
```

But given that I have a lot more `parent` facts, it just iterates through every possible `ancestor` bag.

The last variant I tried:

```
setof(A, ancestor(A, member(X, muse(X)), Z).
```

but that errors out with:

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: setof(A, ancestor(A, member(X, muse(X)), Z)
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: .
```

which makes sense.

I want to be able to write the results, such as:

```
write('The Muses ancestors are: '), write(MuseAncestors), nl.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass a compound goal to a predicate that takes a goal as an argument, just put it in parenthesis:

```
setof(X, ( G1, G2 ), Xs).
```

As to your compound goal: maybe it is better to ask:

> Who are the ancestors of muses?

```
?- muse(M), ancestor(A, M).
```

You need a *conjunction* of goals. Any introductory Prolog text should explain what the conjunction means and why `ancestor(A, muse(M))` is not what you mean.

Keep in mind that if you write:

```
?- setof(A, ( muse(M), ancestor(A, M) ), As).
```

You leave `M` a free variable, and you will get one set of solutions for *each possible binding of this variable*. To avoid this, you can tell Prolog explicitly to not try to bind it:

```
?- setof(A, M^( muse(M), ancestor(A, M) ), As).
As = [gaia, kronos, mnemosyne, oranos, rheia, zeus].
```

Comment: We were so close! This makes perfect sense now... we just started learning prolog not too long ago for an AI class and don't have a book for it, so finding this information through Google is really difficult. Thanks for your answer!